# Trying to run Select Command using .NET

Tags: stored-procedures

Thank You all in advance for the time you dedicate to try to help.  I'm a new developer. I have been trying for a while to write a select command to call a stored procedure located inside a package in Oracle.

This is what my select portion looks like:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM TCM_PRIV_VLT WHERE REC_APV_USR_NR IS NULL"
```

but this Package requires a variable to be passed on:

```
variable rc refcursor;
exec A952FA_AO.PKG_SOX_AUDIT.PRIV_VLT_Get( :rc );
print rc;
```

I surely don't have a clue of how I'm going to pass this value in order to populate my ListView . Any suggestions???